# ember.js Access each context in computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've made a component that shows a business hours widget for the openings hours of a company or employee.

`{{hours-widget hours=businessHours}}`

`businessHours` is an Array property on the Company and Employee model with possibly multiple open/close times per weekday.

`[
    {
        "wday": 0,
        "open": "09:00",
        "closed": "12:00"
    },
    {
        "wday": 0,
        "open": "13:00",
        "closed": "20:00"
    },
    {
        "wday": 4,
        "open": "09:00",
        "closed": "17:00"
    },
    {
        "wday": 5,
        "open": "09:00",
        "closed": "17:00"
    }
]`

What I want to do in my component's template is something like this:

`{{#each wday in weekDays}}
  <div class="weekday-row">
    <h3>{{formattedWeekday}}</h3>
    {{#each hour in filteredHours}}
      <div class="time">
       open: {{hour.open}}
       closed: {{hour.closed}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}`

The problem I have is that I don't know how to access the weekday inside the computed properties `formattedWeekday` and `filteredHours`.

What I want is something like this:

`formattedWeekday: function() {
    moment.weekdays(@get('wday'))
  }.property('wday')`

And a property to return only the entries for the current weekday.

`filteredHours: function() {
    @get('hours').filter(function(item) {
      item.wday == @get('wday')
    })
  }.property('hours', 'wday')`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where is `businessHours` passed? Could you post some jsbin?

Comment: That depends on the scope. This can be in the company's or employee's edit/show template. Both of these 2 models have an "businessHours" property that is an Array as with time entries.

Comment: Ok, I got it. What is filteredHours? Are you trying to to pass parameter to it to filter BusinessHours from company and employee controller?

Comment: I also added a sample for the `filteredHours`. Here I want to filter the list of hours that got added as the component's parameter based on the current weekday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you provided data in inappropriate format. It should have nested childs like in object that you would get using normally ember data. I've created some ugly workaround, check this http://jsbin.com/xanelebago/1/

```
App.HoursWidgetComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  dates: function() {
    hours = this.get('hours');
    wdays = hours.map(function(item) {
      return item.wday;
    }).uniq();

    wdays = wdays.map(function(wday) {
      items = hours.filterProperty('wday', wday).map(function(item) {
        return {
          open: item.open,
          closed: item.closed
        };
      });

      return {
        wday: moment.weekdays(wday),
        hours: items
      };
    });

    return wdays;
  }.property('hours')
});

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{hours-widget hours=businessHoures}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/hours-widget">
    {{#each dates}}
      <h2>{{wday}}</h2>
      Hours:
      <ul>
        {{#each hours}}
        <li>{{open}} - {{closed}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

I hope that this will meet your requirements. 
Anyway, if you can't change your data format I advise you to create Object Controller for each of your loops and use `render` helper instead of `component`.